# Any videos/presentations explaining the concepts of the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, video, presentation

I was wondering if there are any videos (eg. Google Tech Talks) presenting the MVC pattern.

If so, I would highly appreciate any sources you can provide.

Alternatively, what reading material (preferably online) would you recommend to fully understand the pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it normally Model-View-Controller?

Comment: Thanks e100, and sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Talk
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-hV24clJNc

EDIT: better .Net talk http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman

tut
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNkqX4EKADE&feature=related

http://www.enode.com/x/markup/tutorial/mvc.html

Direct from Apple
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Silly Song
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYvOGPMLVDo

Also, are you a registered dev for apple? cause they have videos for download. (Try the 'iPhone Application Development - Getting Started' video at about 5:50 in. 
)

Comment: I'm afraid video 1 is not that informative. Link 2 requires silverlight 3 (won't run on linux yet). Link 3 I have seen, unfortunately it does not actually go into the actual pattern. Unfortunately I am no registered dev at apple. Maybe I'll have to skip the video part and start reading. Thanks though.

Comment: The YouTube vids run on my iPad, so they should not need silverlight... I don't know what woud fix that issue though

Comment: You're right, I thought you linked something else. Sorry about that, though I can't say that .net 3 minutes video is too educative either. Thanks though.

Comment: Heh, it gets tough when i am only able to link free and easily playable videos. i actually own a few explanations that are better than these.

Comment: I will accept your answer, I'm confident this is just a reflection of the internet being far from complete. :)